# How to use 2 different values for the same xml attribute .....is it possible?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, background

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground,@color/blueGray50}"
    >
```

Here I want to make background coloured all the time and selectable when clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_normal"/>
</selector>
```

[More information](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource)

Comment: thanks this helped me solve the issue